# jQuery works in console but not when in a file

Tags: jquery

This is the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( '#menu-item-927' ).on( 'ubermenuopen', function(){
      jQuery('.site-content').addClass('blur');
    });
});
```

It works when I use it in the console but does not work when in a JS file.

Here are the things I have tried:

1. Enqueued script with jQuery dependency `wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', false );` and custom.js does show up in the source.
2. Added `jQuery(document).ready(function()`.

P.S: ubermenuopen is an events API from the UberMenu plugin.

Comment: "custom.js does show up in the source" - but is the file actually loaded? Try adding `alert( 'custom.js' )` in the file and see if you get the alert. Also, there might be other dependencies that you must specify, e.g. `ubermenu`?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, I added ```alert( 'Load me!' );``` in the custom.js file and the alert did show up.

Comment: Which theme is active? child or main?

Comment: @Bhautik Child.

Comment: I tested working fine.

Comment: @StanleyTan, as I said, try adding `ubermenu` as a dependency (`array( 'jquery', 'ubermenu' )`), but you'll need to identify the correct script handle like the 'script' in your `wp_enqueue_script()` code. You could also try enqueueing your script in the footer - set the fifth parameter to `true`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Adding the ```ubermenu``` dependency worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tested and works fine. but you can use the `wp_footer` hook and you can add your custom js. check below code. code will go to the active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_scripts(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( '#menu-item-927' ).on( 'ubermenuopen', function(){
              $('.site-content').addClass('blur');
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_scripts', 10, 1 );
```